# Storing custom data Celery Result

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, persistence

I want to store parts of my parsed result as fields in MongoDB backend, so I can query (MapReduce) them at the end of my execution cycle which is not possible with the standard results stored in celery.

The default fields are :
id,status,date_done,traceback,results,children

I want to store the status_code field as well.
Update State is not effective since the metadata is not stored in backend

Comment: What stops you from having a MongoDB database specifically for this? Your tasks simply insert records to this database instead of you relying on the result backend database.

Comment: I don't want to double the insertions since I have more than 5 million inserts in this. I want to add extra parameters in celery meta results

Comment: Why don't you store the additional fields inside the result you return from the task?